# Chef node is giving 401 error

Tags: chef-infra

I have setup a chef server and workstation. when i am trying to add a node to server it is giving following error.

```
Resource Not Found:
-------------------
The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef_server_url is incorrect.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
chef_server_url "https://amit-virtual-machine:443/organizations/kiwitech.com"
```

but when node machine try to connect with `knife ssl check`, connection was established successfully.

my `client.rb` at node looks likes

```
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://amit-virtual-machine:443/organizations/kiwitech"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"
node_name "node1"
trusted_certs_dir "/etc/chef/trusted_certs"`
```

and my chef version is 12.
This is my first time so any small details would be helpful

Comment: why is there a `kiwitech.com` as organization name in the error message? Copy and paste error?

Comment: How are you trying to add the node to the server?  What commands?

Comment: it is an organization name int the error message.

Comment: knife bootstrap nodeadd --ssh-user admin --ssh-password admin --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name node1 , this command on workstation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out, i did not generated the validation key.After generating the validation key for web console, I replaced it with my older key. and it worked.